# How can I solve R6025 pure vital function call error when I run a sketch of Processing for Kinect v1?

Tags: processing, kinect

I need help with using Kinect v1 with Processing.
When I ran Processing, an R6025 pure vital function call
error occurred.
I attached the images of the error message.
[Error message1: R6025 pure vital function call alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVhs2.jpg)
[Error message2: error in console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS14Z.jpg)

This is the detail of my equipment and software.
Windows 10 laptop (40GB disk left)
Kinect v1 for Windows
Processing 4.2
SimpleOpenNI version 1.96 library in Processing

And this is the code which I used.

```
import SimpleOpenNI.*;
SimpleOpenNI kinect;

void setup() {
 size(640,480);
 kinect = new SimpleOpenNI(this);

 kinect.enableDepth();
 kinect.enableRGB();
}

void draw() {
 kinect.update();
  
 image(kinect.depthImage(),0,0);
 image(kinect.rgbImage(), 640,0);
}
```

Below are the methods I tried.

1. Checking Java and graphic driver version
2. Reinstall Visual C++ and Processing(lower version and last version)
3. Uninstall antivirus software
4. Run the system file checker
5. Perform a Clean Boot
6. Run as administrator authority
7. Use other libraries in Processing

Comment: I've just tested with Processing 4.1.2 on Windows 11 (22H2) and a the [RecorderReplay](https://github.com/totovr/SimpleOpenNI/blob/master/SimpleOpenNI/SimpleOpenNI/examples/OpenNI/RecorderPlay/RecorderPlay.pde) sample using a pre-recorded .oni file for playback and that worked (in lieu of an actual kinect). I recommend trying to find a detailed log of the JavaVM crash (e.g. something like hs_err_pid10448.log where pid#### was the process id of the sketch running: searching for `err_pid` with [everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) might help)...

Comment: ...hard to tell what the exact error is without that log. The `₩` symbol looks strange, but it might be due a multiple languages on your system and unrelated to the error. In the past I've seen VM crashes like this ("Target VM failed to initialize") when some native/c++ function called errored (access violation/segfault/etc.). This could happen for multiple reasons in this case: SimpleOpeniNI native calls (potentially to Kinect driver) or even OpenGL/GPU related. I'd try to isolate the issue...

Comment: 1. If your laptop has multiple GPUs (e.g. an integrated Intel + discrete NVIDIA one) try using `Settings > Graphics Settings > Add an App > Browser > ...Processing.exe` then Options and select `High Performance` to explicitly use the discrete GPU for Processing sketches. Hopefully that solves it. 2. if It is USB Kinect driver related this may be tricker given how old Kinect 1 is. I'd try searching for the native(c++) [OpenNi driver/samples](https://structure.io/openni). After installing the driver try running NiViewer.exe from the OpenNI program files folder. If that runs that's good news. ...

Comment: ... if NiViewer doesn't work, try the [Kinect SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28782) (1.0 or 1.8). If that works, you'd need a separate Processing library that wraps the MS Kinect SDK. If it doesn't it could be a hardware issue: try connecting the kinect to a different machine to ensure it works. If any of the native(c++) samples work (OpenNI or Kinect SDK) but Processing wrappers still don't consider using a bridge app using c++ to talk to the kinect and OSC / Websockets to stream data to Processing (if it's body tracking: for images Spout might work).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tested what you said.

1. When I run NiView.exe it shows a message   An unhandled exception of type: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. Location: kinect_device.KinectStreamlmpl.mainLoop(KinectStreamlmpl*) file: location:\users\tool.lab\outputs\openni2\win32\source\drivers\kinect\kinectstreamimpl.cpp: line 137 Location: kinect_device.KinectStreamlmpl.threadFuc(Void* pThreadParam) file: (same location): line 317  

...

Comment: And then, the black screen pops up with live capture. The black screen closed automatically within 10 seconds.
https://imgur.com/a/VnSdZZf
(It's my first time using Imgur, so I don't know why this web page is age-certifying, but... it's a simple computer screen.)

2. In the case of the Kinect SDK 1.0, it works. I attached the image where I run the Kinect studio and a sample from Kinect SDK 1.0.
https://imgur.com/a/hFgbALy

3. I connected Kinect to another computer, and it showed the same result.

If you know what I should do next, please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your feedback in the comments above it seems to be an issue with OpenNI  (when initialising the Kinect Driver).

It's great news it works with the Kinect for Windows SDK.

I recommend trying a Processing library that wraps the Kinect for Windows SDK such as [Bryan Chung's Kinect4WidowsSDK library](http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/research/kinect-for-processing-library/) (via Contribution Manager):
[image: Kinect4WindowsSDK select in a list of 3 kinect related libraries inside the Contribution Manager Window]

(Hopefully the library example just work. This library relies on the Kinect SDK to be preinstalled (the path to Kinect10.dll to be added to the PATH environment variable))

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I got a detailed error message when I ran a sketch with Kinect4WindowsSDK. The problem was Kinect10.dll, So I downloaded it again.
As you said, there was an issue with the library. Only Kinect4WindowsSDK works. There is no error message running a sketch in Processing.


But I encounter another problem.
I ran a copy of the example on the Kinect4WinSDK library web page, but only the depth image is displayed, not the 4-part screen. It even stops working like very slow stop-motion animation.
https://imgur.com/a/2CgsUU5
...

Comment: I appreciate your help. Since I am a beginner at Kinect, I have no idea of it. If you know something, please let me know.

Comment: @Qwerty Happy to hear you got it working in Processing as well: great work! I'm not sure what the issue is. Are you getting any errors in console ? I wonder if there are USB bandwith issues, though it's unlikely (Kinect 1 still used USB 2.0 and most modern computers have USB 3.0 ports). Can you run the same sample using a different USB port on the same computer ? Do you get the same behaviour on a different computer (isolating the issue: is it hardware/USB or software) ? Can you also try a test where you comment retrieving all streams (rgb, depth, skeleton, etc.) and add one at time...

Comment: ...starting with the rgb image at lower resolution first, then depth image alone (no rgb image) at the lowest resolution available. Let's asume you get this working, what the final goal you're trying to achieve with a Kinect 1 and Processing ? (what functionality do you need ? is it skeleton tracking, processing depth map to point cloud, etc. ?)